# how to get a HTML5 video to download completely before playing?

Tags: html, video, html5-video

I'm building an application that requires 4 videos to run at the same time and uses java-script to remove certain videos and replace them with others.

This all has to happen almost instantly and so I want to be able to have the browser download all the videos before any of them start.

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Thanks,
Mike